# Картинка не отображается при запуске npm run serve, но работает на Live Server

Tags: vue.js, webpack

изображение не открывается при развертывании локального сервера через команду npm run serve. Но все корректно отображается при запуска Live server.

C чем это может быть связано?

Comment: открой консоль разработчика, вкладку console, там будет ошибка, и скорее всего эта ошибка будет ругаться на CORS

Comment: Я просто создал папку img в папке public (рядом с index.html) и положил все необходимые изображения туда. Так все работает.